# Using a sequence to determine a limit; why can we do it in this case?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, fractals, dimension-theory-analysis

Assume $f(r)$ is a non-increasing function of $r$ and consider the limit $$\lim_{r \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{\log{f(r)}}{\log{\frac{1}{r}}}$$
Something I'm reading states:

> Since $f(r)$ is a non-increasing function of $r$ and since $\log{\frac{1}{r}}$ changes very slowly, instead of the limit along all values of $r$ we can take the limit along any sequence $r_j$ such that 
>   $$\frac{\log{\frac{1}{r_j + 1}}}{\log{\frac{1}{r_j}}} \rightarrow 1~~~~~\text{as}~~~~~ j \rightarrow \infty$$

I don't quite understand why any of this is true. I assume that there's some hand-waving going on here, and I also assume that it's happening because I lack pre-requisites.

When I read "... since $\log{\frac{1}{r}}$ changes very slowly..." I think its derivative must be relatively "small." But it's derivative is $-\frac{1}{r}$, whose magnitude gets infinitely high as $r \rightarrow 0$, so I must be mistaken here. What does it mean for $\log{\frac{1}{r}}$ to "change very slowly"?

Why can we use such a sequence in the limit? Is there something specific about *that* sequence (that may be relevant later in the text, or that is covered in some review of a common trick) or is there some general principle here that I'm missing? I have an idea as to when one can use a sequence to evaluate a limit, but the condition for the sequence $r_j$ doesn't fit that intuition—I could understand something more naive, like some sequence where $r_j \rightarrow 0$ as $j \rightarrow \infty$, but I don't think that's equivalent to the condition given (when $r_j \rightarrow 0$, $\log{\frac{1}{r_j + 1}} \rightarrow 1$ and $\log{\frac{1}{r_j}} \rightarrow \infty$, so dividing these probably doesn't go to $1$).

If this is a matter of me lacking some prerequisite and not just being dense, I'd also appreciate any textbook or lecture recommendations. (For context, this is regarding the Minkowski dimension; I've replaced the number of balls necessary to cover some set with $f(r)$.)

(Also, feel free to edit the title to something more descriptive)

Comment: What else do you know about f?

Comment: @GradaGukovic Nothing else; about as much information here is what was presented in the text.

Comment: Which space? $r \in \mathbb{R}$. There mus be a reason why the ratio of the logs is preferred to $\frac{c}{log(1/r)}$

Comment: @GradaGukovic We're looking at $\mathbb{R^n}$. If considering a curve, $f$ is roughly of order $r^{-1}$. If we're looking at a surface, it's roughly of order $r^{-2}$. My intuition is that these details are not relevant, though (but I don't have the expertise to have confidence in my intuition!)

Comment: @GradaGukovic Oh. The reason we're using $f(r)$ is because we're defining the dimension of a subset, $A$, as the number $d$ for which $f(r) = r^{-d}$, where $f(r)$ is the least number of balls of radius $r$ needed to cover $A$. If you solve for $d$, you get that ratio. I'm more concerned about the "changes very slowly" and sequence comments, though